# Seaborn displot with labels on every set of axes?

Tags: python, seaborn

I used the code below to create the image attached to this question. There are a couple things I don't like about the result. One is that it consumes a huge amount of vertical space, all because a single plot has a very large bin. The other is that the axes are labeled only at the left and the bottom, rather than all being labeled. For the y-axis, I think this is fine, but for the x-axis, you have to scroll a long way down to see the axis labels.

```
import seaborn as sns
plot = sns.displot(data=df, col='threshold', col_wrap=2, x='predicted_synonym_count', hue='has_synonym', multiple='stack', binwidth=0.5)
plot.savefig('my_file_name.jpg')
```

I'm specifically asking about how to label all of the x-axes. I will post another question asking about whether I can vary the heights of the plots. Is there any way to label all the x-axes with a seaborn displot or something similar?

[image: A displot consisting of ten histograms representing the predicted number of synonyms for each label, colored according to whether the label has any actual synonyms.]

Comment: Check out this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74850380/how-to-set-x-axis-labelnot-xtick-label-for-all-subplots-in-relplot).